# How to merge 2 queries to work with pagination?

Tags: laravel

I currently have a query that sums the number of non-active users in the last year and groups them by `country` and `city` and then paginates the result:

```
UserData::query()
    ->select(
        country,
        city,
        DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS not_active'),
    )
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subYear(), Carbon::now()])
    ->groupBy('country', 'city')
    ->paginate('500');
```

But I also need to add to each group a column that shows how many active users are of the same group, of all time, not just last year:

```
UserData::query()
    ->select(
        country,
        city,
        DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active'),
    )
    ->groupBy('country', 'city')
    ->get();
```

Then in the frontend I want to display the data in a table so I want the data to be "merged" so that I can output the matching `active` and `not_active` columns together, so the end result should look like that:

```
  country   |    city   | active(all time) | not active(past year)
------------|-----------|------------------|-----------------------
Sweden      | Stockholm |        25        |           1
Switzerland |   Bern    |        43        |           13
```

But how can it be done when using pagination?

I tried to do it with subqueries but that didn't work: (Note that I am using slightly different query checking `whereNull` for active users and `whereNotNull` for non-active users:

```
$result = UserData::select('end_date', 'country', 'city')
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->select('end_date')
    ->whereNull('end_date')
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subYear(), Carbon::now()]);
}, 'active')
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->select('end_date')
    ->whereNotNull('end_date')
}, 'not_active')
->groupBy('country', 'city')
->paginate('500');
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using a [union()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#unions)

```
$first = UserData::query()
                 ->select(
                     'country',
                     'city',
                     DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS not_active'),
                 )
                 ->whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subYear(), now()]);

$second = UserData::query()
                  ->select(
                      'country',
                      'city',
                      DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN end_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS active'),
                  );

$first->union($second)
      ->groupBy('country', 'city')
      ->paginate('500');
```

Which will execute a SQL union query like `select *cols* from *table* where *clause* union (select *cols* from *table* where *someOtherClause*)`

Comment: Thank you, it's not working as expected, there is a problem with the `DB::raw` columns: It will only show the column that's in the `$first` dataset. So in your example there would be the selected columns - `country`, `city` and `not_active` but the `active` disappeared. If I swap and do `$second->union($first)` then it would only show me the `active`, `country` and `city` columns. Using MS SQL if that matters

Comment: Oh right, unions have to have the same columns in the queries being unioned. You could flip the logic for the 2nd query so it also calculates an `active` column instead of `not_active`